# What are these brown spots on my rubber plant?

Tags: houseplants, watering, pest-control

I just discovered these brown spots on some of the lower leaves of my 2-year-old ficus rubber plant. Are these due to some kind of scale bug?

I water the plant about once a week and only if the soil feels dry. The pot has a small drainage hole but I never water it so much that water comes running out of it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the beginnings of a fungal/bacterial infection caused by too much water and not enough light. The light-colored growth rings around the spots are an indication of this. Most healthy plants can outgrow the problem if the cause is addressed. Check that there is good drainage from the pot. Remove the plant from the pot if possible and look at the roots. Black and soft is rotted, firm and brown or white is healthy. Remove any rotted roots. Be sure the roots are not bound. Repotting into a larger container may be necessary. Move the plant to the highest light condition you have and before watering again stick your finger in the soil down one inch. If it is moist then do not water until it is dry. Hope this helps.