# Brown leaves and spots on Baby Rubber Plant (Peperomia Obtusifolia)

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

I have a Peperomia Obtusifolia which has developed brown leaf edges and spots prior to this it was growing well and no issues.

I have tried to diagnose the issue which seems similar to [black spots on rubber tree](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/43205/what-are-these-brown-spots-on-my-rubber-plant) and [brown spots on rubber plant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/43205/what-are-these-brown-spots-on-my-rubber-plant)

When it was first noticed nothing had changed in terms of watering or placement and the only thing would be the seasonal temperature i.e. central heating in the day and no heating at night, the air humidity reads about avg 55%.

I suspected it could be root rot so cut the watering down but the roots/soil looks dry if anything.

Any ideas

[image: Brown Leaves]

[image: Brown Spots]

[image: Roots Side]

[image: Roots Bottom]

Comment: The roots seem healthy to me. Inspect the leaves closely you might spot some pests. In general these spot can be natural imperfections, if you cannot spot any pest I would not worry.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about that , see the new leave it is glossy and shinny , mostly this is due to weather change. I have same plant variegated and not variegated and both have 2 or 3 leaves with slight damage but new leaves are in good shape